# Is global destructors necessary in C/C++ programming?

Tags: c++, c

The `__do_global_ctors_aux` function performs global object contruction when program init.

The `__do_global_dtors_aux` function performs global object destruction when program exit.

The question is that "is `__do_global_dtors_aux` necessary?"

The memory of global object should be reclaimed by OS after program exit.
Although programmer may like to output some result or message in the destructor, I think this can be done at other explicit location inside code. Besides that, the global destructor is seems redundant to me. Do I miss something?

To be more specific, the destruction of non-object type variables neither affect current program behavior nor other system resources. Would it trigger the '__do_global_dtors_aux' function when program exit in C and C++ program?

There is '__do_global_dtors_aux' label in the assembly of the following program compiled with gcc or g++. But I am not sure if it would be run to.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[100];

void func(unsigned int i)
{
    if (i < 100)
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
}

int main()
{
    func(30);
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry about the poor phrasing.

Comment: Memory is obviously not the only thing to worry.

Comment: What is it that you are asking?

Comment: The way classes work in `C++` is that the programmer gets to decide what needs to happen when they are destroyed. Therefor is it *necessary* for the `C++` runtime to call a function to *destruct* all of the programmer's global objects. Relevant concepts [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)

Comment: What I really concern is that some redundant global destruction may hurt performance especially for programs frequently triggered. How to prevent this overhead if programmer knows the global destruction is unnecessary (no shared resources with other program or OS).

Comment: This is actually a very good question despite its poor phrasing.

Comment: If you want to avoid the overhead of global destruction, simply avoid use of global objects altogether (good practice) or ensure that all of your global objects have destructors that don't do anything.   This does mean your global objects should also not use global (system) resources that need to be relinquished.    That said, worrying about such things before you have evidence of the need (e.g. through testing and finding a performance bottleneck as a program is terminating) is called premature optimisation for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than "are global destructors necessary", there are two more important questions to ask:

- Are global destructors useful?
- Can global destructors be relied on?

For the latter, the answer is most emphatically **NO**. There a number of ways a program can die without having any chance to perform any actions (such as `_exit` and `SIGKILL` on Unix-like systems). Even `atexit` and `sigaction` do not allow you to unwind the stack normally.

That said, I would argue that *if* you have to use global variables (it's generally a very good idea *not* to), it is helpful that their destructors will be called, so that you can more easily track resource issues using tools like `valgrind`.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard requires that destructors of globals will be called before the program terminates, in reverse order of their construction.   In C, there are some required actions (e.g. flushing and closing files) as a program terminates as well.

There are objects that manage resources other than memory.   A program which locked a mutex (or a file) and terminated without properly cleaning up would cause trouble for other programs which use the same mutex (or file).

Also, not all operating systems reclaim memory from a terminating process.

Answer (score 0):

Not only global objest reclaimed by OS after process exit but all memory allocate for this process. At least  __do_global_ctors_aux/__do_global_dtors_aux  is good from design perspective.Missing   __do_global_dtors_aux will make people confuse and feel not good. As developer we don't care __do_global_ctors_aux/__do_global_ctors_aux, normally  we focus on constructor/destructor. And release all memory before process exit is good programming habit.